# Why do square bracket appear with the table name?

Tags: sql-server, database

I created a database with couple of tables and some table names are enclosed with square bracket: [table_name]

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to get rid of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of square brackets \[\] in MS-SQL table designer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917196/meaning-of-square-brackets-in-ms-sql-table-designer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use SQL Server Management Studio to script out your objects it will enclose all names with square brackets.

They are only necessary when the name contains a space or a reserved word (such as `[Name])`.

Comment: TIL that it works the same way with sqlite as well. Postgres on the other hand though does not eat it, postgres is happy with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Are the tables in question MSSQL keywords?  It's a common notation to put MSSQL object names in brackets.  It's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets are to indicate that the name represents an object and not a reserved word.  By default SQL Server adds these to make sure the scripts it generates run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Putting square brackets Sql Server allows you to use reserved words or phrases with spaces as identifiers. If your table containes any of these, it's normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a space in your column name.