# Simple INSERT from PHP into SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am attempting to learn PHP and am getting really frustrated attempting to write records into a SQL Server database.  The following simple INSERT query works perfectly inside the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio application but does not insert a record when run from within PHP.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>PHP Database Insert</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $con = mssql_connect('COMPNAME\INSTANCE', 'uid', 'pwd');
            mssql_select_db('TestDB', $con);
            $Tsql = "INSERT INTO [TestTable] (Col1, Col2) VALUES('test1','test2')";
            $result = mssql_query($Tsql,$con);
            mssql_close($con);
            }   
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the brackets around the table name

Comment: Is the `if` block being entered at all?  (That is, is there a POST body?)  Is there an error coming back from the database?  (What's in `$result`?)

Comment: where's the form to go with this? seeing `if (!empty($_POST)) {` suggests that probably isn't actual code for the values.

Comment: I'm not going to stand around all night like someone's personal valet. @ one of us, I'm out of this loop.

Comment: You don't have any special characters such as spaces or reserved names in your table name, so the brackets might be in the way of the `INSERT`. Try removing them, as what ElefantPhace said.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/675848/4885674

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have added the <form> tag to the <body>, as recommended.  I have also removed the brackets from the table name but to no avail.  The form is painted in the browser but I get nothing inserted into the database table.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this

```
$Tsql = "INSERT INTO TestTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES('test1','test2')";
```